# Add a record to a text box using the same button that deletes a record from a different text box

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a button in an access Form that does this command in VBA

```
Private Sub Command12_Click()
On Error GoTo Command12_Click_Err

If Not IsNull (txtSearchbar) Then
  DoCmd.ApplyFilter "", "[Progress] Like "*" & [Forms]![APIReleasing]![txtSearchbar] & ""*""",""
  DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdDeleteRecord
End Sub
```

The thing is that I also want to add the same info entered in `txtSearchbar` to be added to another textbox.  So how do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I would use this filter criteria:

```
"[Progress] Like '*" & Me.txtSearchbar & "*'"
```

Add text to another textbox:

```
Me.txtAnotherTextBox.Value = Me.txtSearchbar.Value
```

`.Value` can be omitted, but in some cases it may lead to incorrect results.

Comment: I tried using
`Me.Serving.Value = Me.txtSearchbar.Value`
and now it gives me the error _Microsoft Access can't find the Field 'Serving' referred to in your expression._ when the text box is called Serving

Comment: Quite sure, this is typo in the name. VBA editor Intellisence should show `Serving` in the list of methods/properties when you type `Me.` Does it show? Select it. Also try to rename `Serving` textbox to, for instance `txtServing`